# Java https request get 403 response code for curseforge site

Tags: java, https

I try get redirect from https://www.curseforge.com/projects/291874 to https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/serene-seasons but all tries response 403. I try HttpURLConnection, HttpsURLConnection and URLConnection but nothing to work.
How do request on this site?
Browser do this two steps:
CONNECT www.curseforge.com:443 HTTP/1.1
GET /projects/291874 HTTP/1.1
How do this on java?
Please check your code before answer (first link in question)

```java
String url  = "https://www.curseforge.com/projects/291874";
        try {
        HttpURLConnection con1 = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());
        con1.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.curseforge.com");
        con1.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0");
        con1.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        con1.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
        con1.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        con1.setRequestProperty("DNT", "1");
        con1.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        con1.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        con1.connect();
        //con1.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(con1.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(con1.getHeaderField("Location"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: A 403 error means your request requires authentication. Check the headers your browser is sending and try adding them to your HttpsURLConnection.

Comment: How i can see headers? firefox

Comment: You probably need to set your `User-Agent` header field.

Comment: I set all headers as in HTTP Header Live from FireFox and still 403